# Could not hide ad immediately after displaying ad on flutter

Tags: dart, admob, flutter

We have created the following class to display AdMob on flutter.

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'package:xxxxx/models/const.dart';

class Ads {
  static BannerAd _bannerAd;

  static init() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: Const.adAppId);
  }

  static BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return new BannerAd(
      adUnitId: Const.adUnitId,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event $event");
      },
    );
  }

  static void showBanner() {
    if (_bannerAd == null) {
      _bannerAd = createBannerAd();
    }

    _bannerAd.load().then((load) {
      _bannerAd.show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
    });
  }

  static void hideBanner() {
    _bannerAd?.dispose();
    _bannerAd = null;
  }

  static final MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = new MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    testDevices: Const.testDevices,
    keywords: Const.keywords,
    birthday: new DateTime.now(),
    gender: MobileAdGender.female,
  );
}
```

The following values are correctly defined in the Const class.

`adAppId`, `adUnitId`, `testDevices`, `keywords`

`init()` is called immediately after startup.
`showBanner()` will be called when showing the ad.
`hideBanner()` will be called when hiding the ad.

These will work as expected in most cases.

But after `_bannerAd.show()` is called, the ad will not be hidden if `hideBanner()` is called before the listener receives `MobileAdEvent.loaded`.

[OK]
`_bannerAd.show()` -> receive `MobileAdEvent.loaded` -> `hideBanner()`

[NG]
`_bannerAd.show()` -> `hideBanner()` -> (receive `MobileAdEvent.loaded`)

How can we avoid this if we do?

Comment: same issue unable to setState. Any solutuion?